# Using pycountry for multi-option AttributeOption in django-oscar

Tags: django-oscar

I'm just starting to learn how to use django-oscar to setup an e-commerce website. Say that I want to sell coffee online, and the beans origin will be from different countries. How do I use the already installed `pycountry` data to show countries as input for the multi-option attribute for a particular product?

[a screenshot of the dashboard to add product on django-oscar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qPRtg.png)

I managed to manually add options through the dashboard, but cannot figure out a way to connect `pycountry` to the dashboard.